# How to return new Selenium page object instance in a python method?

Tags: python, selenium, oop

I need to return a new instance of page object using method in main page

I have an experience writing Selenium tests on java with page object model and I need to implement the same thing in Python.
Here's what I am struggling with:
I have a scenario that when I click on a link in method, the class instance of opening page object returns and I can work with methods of this new returned instance.
In java I can do it like that:

```
public class MainPage extends BasePage {

    public SignInPage clickSignIn(){
        clickElementByXpath(SIGN_IN_OPTION);
        return new SignInPage();
    }
}
```

How do I do that in Python?

Here is an example from a real project that I have, when I try to return page object instance and call method from it there is an error that self should be given as an argument.

```
class MainPage(BasePage):
    def open_good_example_1(self):
        """Open good example 1 and return it's heading."""
        example_heading = GoodExample1.is_heading_displayed(self)
        return example_heading

class GoodExample1(BasePage):
    """Page object model for good menu example.

    Search locators and methods are included here for Selenium tests.
    """

    # Search locators
    GOOD_MENU_EXAMPLE_HEADING = "//h1[@id='good-menu-example-heading']"

    def is_heading_displayed(self):
        """Find and return heading to check if it is displayed in test."""
        return self.find_element_by_xpath(self.GOOD_MENU_EXAMPLE_HEADING)
```

So, how can I call an instance of good example 1 in main page in Python as I can do it in Java?

Comment: Does this help? https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/page-objects.html

Comment: Thank you for the link! It turned out that the error was unrelated to this problem :-)